# Modify jQuery plugin: Treeview script to expand and collapse function -> exclude area

Tags: javascript, css

I am still new to JS and CSS and I am having trouble modifying the script.

In the essence, the script has a tree, and each `comment` has an area around it, so when you click on the area, the plugin expands or collapses. Since I use links in the tree, they are clickable, but if you miss the link while you click, the tree is collapsing. I want only `+` and `-` do the expansion/collapsing.

http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/

CSS: http://qwertysella.us/jquery.treeview.css

JS: http://qwertysella.us/jquery.treeview.js

I tried disabling clicks, but it did not solve the problem completely -- it clicks, but not always:

```
.treeview .hover { 
/*    cursor: pointer; */
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

I understand, this is not very good build question, but I need an advise where to look. Since after hours  of trial and error, I am unable to determine the solution.
In firebug, I see that when I point at the area, it is `span.file.hover`, but I am unable to find any onclick event for it... Kind of stuck.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function that I needed to disable:

```
//   this.filter(":has(>ul):not(:has(>a))").find(">span").unbind("click.treeview").bind("click.treeview", function(event) {
//                // don't handle click events on children, eg. checkboxes
//                if ( this == event.target )
//                    toggler.apply($(this).next());
//                                alert(event.target);
//            }).add( $("a", this) ).hoverClass();
```